# In Cascading dropdown fails but first works fine using jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown that lists the data fetched from database using `PHP and jQuery Ajax`.

1. First dropdown List fetches data successfully and populates it in the dropdown.

**HTML for first dropdownlist :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
        $(function() {   
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getGroupzBase.php', 
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                // Call this function on success                
                    console.log(data);
                   var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                   console.log(yourArray);                                           
                    $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {                 
                        $('#builder_group').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: yourArray.id,
                            text : yourArray.name, 
                        }));
}); 
},
error: function() {
    displayDialogBox('Error', err.toString());
}
});              
});
```

And the dropdown tag -

```
<select id="builder_group"></select>
```

1. For the second dropdown menu does not work with the first dropdown. I have to use jQuery Ajax for the second dropdown as well.
   **HTML for second dropdownlist :**

   ```
     <script>
       $("#builder_group").change(function(){
           console.log("Hello 1");
           $('#Ivrmapping_groupZCode').find('option').remove().end(); //clear the city ddl
           var builder = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
           alert(builder);
           //do the ajax call
           $.ajax({
               url:'getGroupzCode.php'
               type:'GET',
               data:{city:builder},
               dataType:'json',
               cache:false,
           success: function(data) {
                       // Call this function on success                
                           console.log(data);
                          var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                          console.log(yourArray);                                           
                           $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {                 
                           );
       }); 
       },
       error: function() {
           displayDialogBox('Error', err.toString());
       }
       }); 

           }); 

       });
   </script>
   ```

And the dropdown tag -

```
<select name="Ivrmapping[groupZCode]" id="Ivrmapping_groupZCode">..
</select>
```

Why is the second dropdownlist not working with first.
Can we have more than one jQuery Ajax calls in one page.

Comment: Yes definitely we can have them.. is your console.log(data) giving you fine results(as you expect)..

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt No I don't see any of those console.log in second jQuery ajax script

Comment: I think you are passing in value... shouldn't you be passing id value in city:builder

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt Still if I place alert before that atleast that should work right

Comment: Yes that should work, are you sure you are handling the value (of builder) at back end rather than the id.. might be a silly mistake. I don't see any other problem, Have you tried to look at the response of the ajax call in console of browser.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt My confirmation is that it is not calling the script itself

Comment: if you are using google chrome browser, then `rightclick->inspectelement->network` and check whether `getGroupzCode.php` occurs twotimes after page refresh. If so both codes are working.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem of brackets:: Try this:

```
$("#builder_group").change(function(){
        console.log("Hello 1");
        $('#Ivrmapping_groupZCode').find('option').remove().end(); //clear the city ddl
        var builder = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        alert(builder);
        //do the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url:'getGroupzCode.php'
            type:'GET',
            data:{city:builder},
            dataType:'json',
            cache:false,
        success: function(data) {
                    // Call this function on success                
                        console.log(data);
                       var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                       console.log(yourArray);                                           
                        $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {/* your plan*/});
    },
    error: function() {
        displayDialogBox('Error', err.toString());
    }
    }); 
    });
```

And you should use firebug, or chrome, these errors are clearly shown on the console. Try it out.